# MPEG4 X264 vs NVENC H264 encoding play compatibility on old devices

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I always encoding videos on `x264`, this encoding work well on old devices or mobile phones.
To increase the encoding speed I try to replace encoding method with `NVENC H264` with nVidia GPU.

**Question 1** : Device combability for play the `NVENC H264` is different with `x264` ?
**Question 2** : Old devices can play `NVENC H264` file same as `x264` ?

**Old devices** : (All devices that can play x264) Android 6+, TV Setup box, TV, Google chrome 48+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H264 is a decoder specification, not an encoder specification. To be an h264 encoder, it must produce a stream that is decodable by all h264 decoders.

So, yes the files will still work.

Note however that h264 has profiles and levels. So if a devise doesn’t play a file, it’s because the level or profile is too high.